# No Handoff icon in dock

Tags: iphone, mac, dock, continuity

I'm missing handoff icon in dock. I remember that when I had open safari/messenger on my iPhone, I could easily click on the icon that showed on left side of dock.

It's not there anymore. What could be the issue?
Handoff is working correctly, I can copy text from mac->iPhone, and iPhone -> mac, I can open website on iPhone from Mac.

The only issue is that I am missing the icon.
Video: https://youtu.be/--MMBRgPvFs

Comment: Couple things to test would be turning bluetoth on both devices off and on again. Are they all on the newest OS versions?

Comment: I did all of that. Turn of iPhone, Mac, disconnect Bluetooth etc. And yes, all on latest soft

Answer (score 1):

this is what I have observed. your tab in iOS was in private  mode and macOS was in normal. so it was easily transferred to iOS but got opened in private mode which in turn could not be opened in Mac.

Do tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope, both are in normal mode. It’s not only the case with browser. Messages should work as well.